# LoadError Unable to autoload constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload

It seems that autoloader is loading up lib/tools/address and not my model

Address throws the following error

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Address, expected
>   /lib/tools/address.rb to define it

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I thought that
Address would point to constant models/address.rb
and
Tools::Address to lib/tools/address.rb

app/models/address.rb

```
class Address
  blah
end
```

lib/tools/address.rb

```
module Tools
  class Address
    blah blah
  end
end
```

Comment: there's a missing end in lib/tools/address.rb. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @jaydel yea, just a typo

Answer (score 8):

In my experience it can be tricky to use multiple constants with the same name but with different namespaces. In your case you have two `Address` constants, one at the top level and another inside the `Tools` namespace. This can confuse the Rails autoloader.

Some possible solutions:

When you want to use the top-level `Address` (i.e. your model), refer to it explicitly using `::Address`.

If that doesn't work, you can also use `require_dependency` to give the autoloader a hint of what you want. At the top of the file that is giving you the LoadError, put this line:

```
require_dependency("address")
```

Here's the documentation:

> **require_dependency**
>
> Interprets a file using mechanism and marks its defined constants as autoloaded. file_name can be either a string or respond to to_path.
>
> Use this method in code that absolutely needs a certain constant to be defined at that point. A typical use case is to make constant name resolution deterministic for constants with the same relative name in different namespaces whose evaluation would depend on load order otherwise.