# How to namespace in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I've got a rails model called LeadSource

```
class LeadSource < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I also have in the lib directory, the following structure:

```
-lib
  -reports
    base.rb
    lead_source.rb
```

in the lead_source.rb, i've got this defined:

```
module Reports
  class LeadSource < Reports::Base
  end
end
```

When I call LeadSource.new in the console, I get the following error:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant LeadSource, expected ..../lib/reports/lead_source.rb to define it
```

I am under the assumption that the module Reports should be namespacing my LeadSource class. (allowing me to have two classes named the same thing). But why in this case, when I try to instantiate a new LeadSource object (active record model) is rails looking in lib and throwing a fit about my class defined there?

I would expect to call the active record model like this:

```
LeadSource.new
```

and the class in my lib like this:

```
Reports::LeadSource.new
```

without them colliding and causing issues.

EDIT:

I feel like this defeats the purpose of namespacing if the solution is to just change the class name as pointed out here as well as the similar question marked as duplicate of this one.

Am I wrong in thinking that a namespace should silo off the resource and not just make it so i have to type more to call it? seems silly to me.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but could you try and rename `Reports` to `Report` (and the containing directory as well). You shouldn't have plural module names anyway. Autoloading is a strange beast sometimes.

Comment: It might be that you have two files called `lead_source.rb` which could be confusing the auto-loader. Have you tried using an alternate name? Having these two named the same is going to be trouble. You'll need to refer to `::LeadSource` in the Reports context.

Comment: Worth a try to extraxt the report lead class into the file that the error recommends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LoadError Unable to autoload constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777480/loaderror-unable-to-autoload-constant)

Comment: thanks for suggestions. I changed reports to report_builder (I have a model named report, so just to be safe). That didn't fix it. I have the same error.